# GWT Highcharts, Java, and xml UiBinder?

Tags: java, xml, gwt, highcharts, uibinder

I want to know how to use GWT Highcharts to display a graph with a xml UiBinder.
I have been looking at the examples of how Highcharts looks in Java. I copied this example from the Moxie Group: GWT Highcharts page and I pasted it in a Java class that I created:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.*;
import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.labels.DataLabels;
import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.plotOptions.LinePlotOptions;

public class LineChart implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(createChart());
}




    public Chart createChart () {

        final Chart chart = new Chart()
                .setType(Series.Type.LINE)
                .setChartTitle(new ChartTitle()
                                .setText("Monthly Average Temperature")
                )
                .setChartSubtitle(new ChartSubtitle()
                                .setText("Source: WorldClimate.com")
                )
                .setToolTip(new ToolTip()
                                .setEnabled(false)
                );

        chart.getXAxis()
                .setCategories(
                        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
                );

        chart.getYAxis()
                .setAxisTitleText("Temperature Â°C");

        chart.setLinePlotOptions(new LinePlotOptions()
                        .setEnableMouseTracking(true)
                        .setDataLabels(new DataLabels()
                                        .setEnabled(true)
                        )
        );

        chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()
                        .setName("Tokyo")
                        .setPoints(new Number[]{
                                7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6
                        })
        );
        chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()
                        .setName("London")
                        .setPoints(new Number[]{
                                3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8
                        })
        );

        return chart;
    }

}
```

Now, I want to see if this is working on my project. What do I need to do? Should I create a main method to display the graph? and how do I reference this gram from a xml UiBinder?

I want the line graph to be displayed in a page that is formatted in a UiBinder but if I could at least see the graph running that would help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: I have lot of questions: Did you create a proper gwt project (with a module file .gwt.xml)? What is your project? Do you really need UiBinder? Please give more details, I'll gladly help.

Comment: @GuillaumeRebesche This is a project that I am doing for a company. They gave me a shell; it basically includes various java classes and a UiBinder to display the page. I am required to use GWT Highcharts to display a graph. I created a java class, LineChart.java and copied and pasted the above code from an example. Now I want to know how to run it.

Comment: Consider using another wrapper : http://highcharts4gwt.github.io/
demo : http://data-dragon-766.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download and include jquery and highcharts javascript in your myApp.html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
```

Then you need to download and include `highcharts.jar` as a dependency of your project.

Then you need to include the highcharts module into you gwt project (`myApp.gwt.xml`):

```
<inherits name="org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.Highcharts"/>
```

After that you can start using UiBinder.

Create a `Composite` in your source directory: for the example, let's pretend your pakage is `com.mycompany`. So create a class `com.mycompany.MyChart.java`

```
package com.mySampleApplication.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.*;

import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.labels.DataLabels;
import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.plotOptions.LinePlotOptions;

public class MyChart extends Composite {


    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<FlowPanel, MyChart> {
    }

    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    @UiField(provided = true)
    public final Chart chart;

    public MyChart() {
        chart = new Chart()
                .setType(Series.Type.LINE)
                .setChartTitle(new ChartTitle().setText("Monthly Average Temperature"))
                .setChartSubtitle(new ChartSubtitle().setText("Source: WorldClimate.com"))
                .setToolTip(new ToolTip().setEnabled(false));

        chart.getXAxis()
                .setCategories(
                        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
                );

        chart.getYAxis().setAxisTitleText("Temperature Â°C");

        chart.setLinePlotOptions(new LinePlotOptions()
                        .setEnableMouseTracking(true)
                        .setDataLabels(new DataLabels()
                                        .setEnabled(true)
                        )
        );

        chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()
                        .setName("Tokyo")
                        .setPoints(new Number[]{
                                7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6
                        })
        );
        chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()
                        .setName("London")
                        .setPoints(new Number[]{
                                3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8
                        })
        );

        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

Then create the corresponding UiBinder file in your ressource folder `com.mycompany.MyChart.ui.xml`

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:highcharts="urn:import:org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client">

    <g:FlowPanel>
        <highcharts:Chart ui:field="chart"/>
    </g:FlowPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

And finnally create your chart composite and add it to the DOM

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(new MyChart());
}
```

It could be a lot easier if you don't use UiBinder, but it seems to be a requirement for you.